# React with Webpack, ES6, simple component does not display

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

This is my `webpack-config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
        entry: "./src/js/main.js",
        output: {
            path: './dist',
            filename: 'bundle.js',
            publicPath: './dist'
        }, 
        devServer:{
            inline: true,
        contentBase: './dist'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader:'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I created simple component `App.js`:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return <h1>Hello</h1>
    }
}
```

and my `main.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App.js';

render(<App/>, document.getElementById('main'));
```

My `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main"></div>
    <script src="bundle.js">,/scrip>
</body>
</html>
```

when I run `webpack-dev-server`,  there is no errors, it is serve right folder , but I see empty page, with no errors in the WEB console.
I see it loads the right file with id `main`, but thats all.

Where is the problem ?

Comment: Do you have an `index.html`?

Comment: Yes, like i wrote `I see it loads the right file with id main`

Comment: And did you link your bundle.js with `<script src="bundle.js">` in the index?

Comment: Yes, I edit the question to be clear, thx.

Comment: Is it a typo or `<script src="bundle.js">,/scrip>` should be `<script src="bundle.js"></script>` ?

Comment: Thx, just couple of hours :(, now it works. Please, add this like answer, because it is the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your html file, the closing script tag is broken.

> ,/scrip>

Answer (score 1):

your file is named `App.jsx` but you're trying to import from `App.js`